# Using browsermob concurrently

Tags: selenium, proxy, testng, selenium-grid, har

i am using testng, selenium-grid to run selenium tests in parallel with browsermob proxy. I could have up to 100k tests in total run in parallel mode by batches of 10 tests (default testng parallel behaviour).

As soon as tests are run in parallel I couldn't use one proxy so each test create its own proxy binded to new free port (for ex. i use range 9200-9400), then of course I try to reuse every given port as soon as the test is finished.

The problem is that sometimes  proxy doesn't capture any traffic and HAR file returns 0 entries (i am using function proxy.getHar() in Java wrapper for REST API).
I suppose this could be due to some glitches of parallel mode, when i re-test the same tests that failed but now running them sequentially It WORKS OK.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong and maybe could recommend some references of using browsermob when running lot's of tests 100k, 1000k in parallel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of browser do you use? If FF you can use Firebug instead of Browsermob.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Currently I am using FF but crossbrowser testing are to come soon. Anyway services like saucelabs.com or testingbot.com seems to be all successfully using browsermob.